# Uncorrelated sequence of r.v. with bounded variance implies $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\rightarrow^{L^2}0$

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to prove the next:

Suppose $\{X_n, n\geq 1\}$ is an uncorrelated sequence, meaning $Cov(X_i,X_j)=0,\quad i\neq j.$

If there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $Var(X_n)\leq c$ for all $n\geq 1,$ then for any $\alpha>1/2$ we have $$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n^{\alpha}}\xrightarrow{L^2}0.$$

My attempt is based in the next: Because of uncorrelated r.v. we have $E(X_iX_j)=E(X_i)E(X_j)$ for all $i\neq j.$ Then:

$\begin{eqnarray}||\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n^{\alpha}}||_{2}^{2}&=&\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(X_i^2)+\sum_{i\neq j}^{n}E(|X_iX_j|)\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(X_i^2)+\sum_{i\neq j}^{n}E(|X_i|)E(|X_j|)\right)\\
&\leq&\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}\left(nc+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(|X_i|)\right)^2\right)
\end{eqnarray}$

but I cannot bound sum of expectations.

Any kind of help is thanked in advance.

Comment: Recall that $$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}\right\|_2^2=\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}{\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]},$$ without the absolute values. You are going to need another assumption, though, because the case $X_n=n$ (or even $X_n=1$) satisfies your current setting but not your conclusion.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the help. With the assumption $E(X_i)=0$ for each random variable everything is fine.